# Create a snapshot after a buying a product in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've a little problem, I need to create a snapshot from a message that is shown after a product is bought, think it as some sort of confirmation receipt from the seller.

My idea is to create this snapshot using html to canvas (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas), I managed to create a modal window and paste the DOM elements in there after the product is bought.

Because we cannot print html elements directly to canvas, this tutorial creates a SVG image that represents the contents of this html, in this case, the receipt. The problem is that I'm not getting the styles, just the information.
Let me expand a little:

Imagine we have this SVG and we need to print it to the canvas.

**Snapshot.js**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const message = '<div class="part-modal-dialog">' +
                    '<div class="content-dialog">' +
                        '<p class="trade"> Sell buy rent 1220 @2210</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';

var data = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>' +
       '<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>' +
        '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
         '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
           '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
                 message +
           '</div>' +
         '</foreignObject>' +
        '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url); 
}
img.src = url;
```

With this code, the snapshot displays the correct information however no styles are present.
I tried to load the styles following this document https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS but no success...

I'm thinking maybe it's not working because this data it's been interpreted as a string (I refer to var data). I also tried to convert this SVG code to XML using jquery but no success...

I also tried **rasterizedHTML** library, but I have the same problem, I'm not getting the styles working.
I tried to load the styles from an URL, and from a local file. Loading from an URL may cause CORS issues.

**I updated the code,** I think this is due to invalid XML although in the validator says it's a well formed XML.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the example you linked first in your post shows the SVG with styling - you have a javascript element pasted in the middle - what does the `message.innerHTML` contain? Test it with hardcoded HTML first, just to see if you get the correct output then? Did you read this in the link?: "Since SVG must be valid XML, you need to parse HTML to get the well-formed output of the HTML parser. The following code is the easiest way to parse HTML." and then the example after it?

Comment: Yes, I've already tested with hardcoded HTML, and it's rendering ok.
You're right, the message.innerHTML has all the classes but I'll check that part of the doc now, I really miss it, I'm going to make an example and test it that way, thanks for your response.

Comment: Just updated the code so we can have a better look at the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HTMLCanvasElement` object's `toDataURL` function which will get u a `data::` URI with the image's contents, as follow:

```
window.open('', document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I brought the styles file from a remote server using jquery ajax and promises from ES6.
Refer to this page https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS *using the style element*. 
Check the code

```
import $ from 'jquery';

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
$.ajax('someurl.com/file.css').then(
    function success(contents) {
      const myStylesheet = contents;
      const message = '<div class="part-modal-dialog">' +
                        '<div class="content-dialog">' +
                            '<p class="trade"> Sell buy rent 1220                   @2210</p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

    var data = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>' +
           '<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>' +
            '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200"    height="200">' +
     '<defs>' +
        '<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[' +
             myStylesheet +
        ']]></style>' +
      '</defs>' +

      '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
                     message.innerHTML +
               '</div>' +
     '</svg>';

    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

    img.onload = function () {
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
       DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url); 
    }
    img.src = url;
 }
 function rejected(reason) {
      console.log(reason); 
});
```

**Be careful with the syntax, it's not a 100% accurate, but the point is to share the idea**

After diving into different resources this is the only way I make this thing work.
Thanks for your help.